# Looking for one lined JavaScript Regex replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm searching for a JavaScript Regex replace in one "command".

It should replace asterisks within four brackets (two on each side) with the HTML charcode `&#9733;` (★) within a span class="stars". There is a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 5 asterisks.

The replace is applied to a large text, so multiple replaces should function.

Example:

```
{{*}}
{{**}}
{{***}}
{{****}}
{{*****}}
```

should be replaced by:

```
<span class="stars">&#9733;</span>
<span class="stars">&#9733;&#9733;</span>
<span class="stars">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
<span class="stars">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
<span class="stars">&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;&#9733;</span>
```

Comment: your input string is {{*}} or <span class="stars">*</span>

Comment: my input string is {{*}}. I have a text which contains multiple {{*}}. within the text that should be replaced by <span class="stars">★</span>

Comment: Why "in one line"? Surely a better criteria are is that it works, is robust, cross-browser and reasonably efficient.

Comment: just to make it a bit harder for you guys ;) haha, no just kiddin' I want to spill as much space as possible within the JS..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really one line, but this works

```
var t = document.getElementById("container").innerHTML;
t = t.replace(/{{(\*{1,5})}}/g,function(m, g) {
    return "<span class='star'>"+new Array(g.length+1).join("&#9733;")+"</span>";
});
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = t;
```

Comment: almost.. it allows 6 asterisks within my curly braces (and like you mentioned, not in one line): http://jsfiddle.net/Aba2K/

Comment: yes, you can use `\*{1,5}` if you want to be sure. will edit. i'm not sure you can do it in just one line actually. but let us know if you figure it out.

Comment: **Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/FeMGL/ @Tetaxa Consider using white-space more generously. Also, you don't want to query for the "container" element twice - just cache the reference. Interesting usage pattern for `new Array( length )` `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(/\{\{(\*{1,5})\}\}/, function (s1, s2) {
    var i, str = "<span class='stars'>";
    for (i = 0; i < s2.length; i += 1) {
        str+= "&#9733;";
    }
    str+= "</span>"
    return str;
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work, see http://jsfiddle.net/eAZM8/ it only replaces one occurence..

Comment: You did not state whether you were using string interpolation or actual HTML.  I assumed the best (string interpolation) where this works fine.  I don't need to see your fiddle, thnx.

Comment: I'm using HTML, but that I can tweak myself :) thanks for asking.

Comment: For future reference, manipulating HTML directly is orders of magnitude more expensive than manipulating strings.  Whenever possible, use strings.

Answer (score 0):

One line:

```
s.replace('{{','<span class=stars>').replace(/\*/g,'&#9733;').replace('}}','</span>');
```